# Как сохранить значение в массиве указателей

Tags: c++, c

Есть приблизительно такой-же код

```
struct TestStruct
{
    int** massive = nullptr;
    int count = 0;
    void AddMassive(int value)
    {
        massive = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
        massive[count++] = value;
    }
};

void func(TestStruct test)
{
    int random = rand() % 30;
    test.AddMassive(random);

}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    TestStruct test;
    func(test);
    return 0;

}
```

Проблема в том что когда функция `func` завершаеться то massive в структуре test становиться пустой. Вопрос как сделать так что-бы даже в `main` в тест осталость значение `random`?

Comment: Немного не ясно, должна быть матрица или все же массив?

Comment: Давай [mcve], а не примерно некомпилирующийся код.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, вы хотели чего-то такого?

```
struct TestStruct
{
    int* massive = nullptr;
    int count = 0;
    void AddMassive(int value)
    {
        massive = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 1);
        massive[count++] = value;
    }
};

void func(TestStruct& test)
{
    int random = rand() % 30;
    test.AddMassive(random);

}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    TestStruct test;
    func(test);
    cout << *test.massive;
}
```

Но этот код, скажем очень мягко, далек от совершенства... Утечка памяти, невозможность добавления хотя бы второго значения, применение `malloc` в C++...

Comment: Для более подробной информации почитайте как работает передача параметров, я предлагаю `Metanit`: https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/3.3.php

Comment: @RottenRat Надеюсь, это вы не мне? :)

Comment: Нет, конечно, Ваш ответ полностью правдив и я собирался ответить точно также. Просто я обычно дополняю ответы ссылкой на обучающий сайт в случаях, если вижу, что вопрос относится к уровню новичка в определенном ЯП